# How to fix put() conflicts with Cloud Datastore ndb model (Google App Engine)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

There is a model having following property:

```
userEmailList = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
```

Data is saved from one function. Whole list property is fetched whenever new email is added to **userEmailList**.

```
if useremail not in thd.userEmailList: #thd is kind object
    thd.userEmailList.append(useremail)
    thd.put()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Some of the users are not added in the list. how to fix this for random emails. As we've added delay for put() but still problem remains same.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Looks like you are doing this concurrently and overwriting your own data.  Check out transactions.